# using factory service for http calls and using them through controller

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an app on MEAN stack. I made factory to handle my http requests and then using that service in my controller.

service

```
.factory('dataSvc', function($q, $http, $timeout, $rootScope, $resource) {

var dataSvc = {};

dataSvc.list = function(options) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    return $http.get(options.url).success(function(data) {
        console.log('========data========', data)
        defer.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(err){
        console.log('======err=======', err)
        defer.reject(err);
    });

    return defer.promise;
}

return dataSvc;
});
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. even if I get 401 status from backend I always end up in success function, So what I am doing wrong here.
2. also If I remove **return** from $http.get then the functionality breaks. So What is the need for this return keyword in front of $http.get

controller

```
dataSvc.list({url: '/api/users'}).then(function(result) {
    console.log('result here===========', result);
    if(result.status == 401) {

    }
    else {

    }

});
```

and also what is the difference between then method and success and error methods provided by angular ?

Answer (score 1):

You could return `$http.get` object rather than creating your own `promise`, because `$http.get` does return a promise object itself. After that you need to use `.then` function over that `$http.get` which will have 1st function which will get call when promise gets resolved & other function will get called when promise gets rejected.

Then response object your received in `.then` function has various data present in it.

> **data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
>   **status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
>
> **headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
>
> **config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
>
> **statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

**Code**

```
dataSvc.list = function(options) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    return $http.get(options.url).then(function(response) {
        console.log('========response========', response)
        return response;
    }).error(function(err){
        console.log('======err=======', err)
        return err;
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
dataSvc.list({url: '/api/users'}).then(function(result) {
    console.log('result here===========', result);
    if(result.status == 401) {

    }
    else {

    }

});
```

Comment: yeah it worked, but still I am not getting that why I am getting the error response like 401 in success callback.

Comment: I am using node js in backend and here is the code



`var checkAuth = function (req, res) {
    if (req.isUserLoggedIn) {
        //handle success case
    }
    else {
        res.send(401, 'not authorised')
    }
};`


I am sending 401 if user is not logged in

Comment: If I am using http.get directly in controller then I am getting err in error callback

Comment: @BhushanGoel try `res.status(401).send('not authorised')`

Comment: still getting it in success callback.

Comment: It is resolved, That was my mistake...I was using http interceptor and in the responseError I was simply returning the rejection instead of returning $q.reject(rejection).